# Equivalent to config --global alias for bash

Tags: bash

In Git, adding an alias is super easy. You just type:

```
git config --global alias.df diff
```

And then it's done!

Adding a config to linux is more work. You have to open your .bash_profile, find where the aliases are stored and then enter it in.

Is there a similarly easy, single command solution for Linux?

Comment: Use the alias command

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "alias df=diff" >>~/.bash_profile
```

Relative to the work to memorize the aliases that you define, it seems like a small effort to open a file with a text editor.